# Flowbite isn't integrated properly

Tags: tailwind-css, flowbite

I can't get Flowbite to install properly. I followed the instructions in the quickstart section and still can't get results.
First of all I installed flowbite globally using:

```
$ npm install flowbite -g
```

Then I added to the tailwind.config.js file this two options:

```
 plugins: [
        require('flowbite/plugin')
    ],
 content: [
        "./node_modules/flowbite/**/*.js"
    ]
```

But still get this error when I tried to watch the css file for the tailwind conversion:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'flowbite/plugin'
Require stack:
- C:\Users\yuki8\Desktop\Food Search Engine\tailwind.config.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1077:15)
    at Function.resolve (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:116:19)
    at _resolve (C:\Users\yuki8\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tailwindcss\node_modules\jiti\dist\jiti.js:1:250100)
    at jiti (C:\Users\yuki8\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tailwindcss\node_modules\jiti\dist\jiti.js:1:252409)
    at C:\Users\yuki8\Desktop\Food Search Engine\tailwind.config.js:7:13
    at evalModule (C:\Users\yuki8\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tailwindcss\node_modules\jiti\dist\jiti.js:1:255106)
    at jiti (C:\Users\yuki8\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tailwindcss\node_modules\jiti\dist\jiti.js:1:253034)
    at C:\Users\yuki8\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\lib\load-config.js:37:30
    at loadConfig (C:\Users\yuki8\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\lib\load-config.js:39:6)
    at Object.loadConfig (C:\Users\yuki8\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\tailwindcss\lib\cli\build\plugin.js:135:49) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    'C:\\Users\\yuki8\\Desktop\\Food Search Engine\\tailwind.config.js'
  ]
```

EDIT: I got it to work, the require field doesn't need "/plugin" after it. I tested with the example provided in the documentation and it works, I still don't get it how I was supposed to know since I followed the few step carefully

Answer (score 0):

You'd want to install flowbite **not** globally, but **locally** to the project. This is so that the `require()` in `tailwind.config.js` can find the package in the location it expects, `node_modules`. Thus, consider running in the root of the project:

```bash
npm install flowbite
```

Notice the lack of the `-g` flag, thus making the install local to the project.

Comment: I still get the an error, it's weird since the directory isn't complicated at all, it's everything in the same folder
npm ERR! code E404
npm ERR! 404 Not Found - GET https://registry.npmjs.org/tailwdincss - Not found
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404  'tailwdincss@*' is not in this registry.
npm ERR! 404
npm ERR! 404 Note that you can also install from a
npm ERR! 404 tarball, folder, http url, or git url.

Comment: You seem to have mispelled `tailwindcss` somewhere in your project. Notice how the error message mentions `tailwdincss`, not `tailwindcss`.

Comment: Oh yeah, I have corrected that but i get the error i copypasted in the original post. It's what I tried at first really but got the same error twice

Comment: Try running `npm install flowbite` again now that the `tailwdincss` misspelling has been corrected.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, it was installed successfully, I could see the directory being created normally. Though, I resolved the issue, I edited the original post